# Clear Interval setted on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setinterval

I'm setting an interval on `componentDidMount()` and saving it on my App state.

The timer starts correctly, but I don't achieve to clear it when I want. This is the initial state:

```
this.initialState = {
            score: 0,
            finished: false,
            currentQuestion: 0,
            questions: [],
            minutes: 1,
            seconds: 15,
            timer: 0
};
```

The action looks like this. It receives a timer (interval) as a parameter:

```
export function updateTimer(timer) {
    return {
        type: UPDATETIMER,
        payload: {
            timer
        }
    }
}
```

I have this action creator function on my `reducers.js`:

```
function timer(state = 0, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case RESTART:
            return 0;
        case UPDATETIMER:
            if(action.payload.timer !== undefined){
                return action.payload.timer;
            }else {
                clearInterval(state);
                return 0;
            }           
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In App.js I use it like this:

```
<Navbar 
            onUpdateTimer= {
              (timer) => {
                this.props.dispatch(updateTimer(timer))
              }
            }
/>
```

What I'm tryng to do is that if I the call has an argument it sets the interval, and if it doesn't it clears it.

The component that calls the action is this one:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CountDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this);
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.props.onUpdateTimer(setInterval(this.countDown, 1000));
  }

  countDown() {
    let minutes = this.props.minutes;
    let seconds = this.props.seconds - 1;
    if (seconds === 0) { 
      if(minutes !== 0){
        minutes -=1;
        seconds = 59;
      }else {
        this.props.timeUp()
        setTimeout(function(){
          alert("SE HA ACABADO EL TIEMPO");
        },0);
      }
    }
    this.props.onUpdateTime(minutes, seconds);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div id="clockdiv">
          <span className="minutes">{this.props.minutes} : </span>
          <span className="seconds">{this.props.seconds}</span>
        </div>
      );
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.startTimer();
  }
}
```

Am I using correctly `clearInterval(state)` in the action creator function?

Comment: How should we know? You don't show us where you call that function. You just pass it as a parameter to a different function, which you also don't show.

Comment: @JaredSmith I wanted to give you a general idea of the App because I think the error is the way how I access to the previous state 'timer' on the action creator function. However I edited the post and added the component that calls the action.

Comment: It kinda sorta looks correct? You seem to be calling it on the integer handle returned from `setInterval`. There's a lot of extra stuff here, setting up a minimal test case might help.

Comment: @JaredSmith Would it help if I upload a download link to my project?